# prices without decimals in GA4 Ecommerce Tracking with GTM and Datalayers

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I have set up GA4 and GTM, connected it with shopify and implemented a datalayers snippet into shopify following this github repo: https://github.com/TechnicalWebAnalytics/dataLayer-shopify

Now my problem is that the prices which are tracked are without decimals in GA4 and so the revenue is way too high. I found that in the dataLayer-allPages.js file there is for every price an modificator that tells 'remove: ","' I guess that this is the problem. I have removed those modificators and in GTM Debugger it now shows the prices with decimal places but in GA4 I can't see transactions for the time after I have made those changes.

[image: Screenshot of dataLayer-allPages Snippet]

Here I have marked the prices that are tracked in GTM Debug View after I have removed the *remove: ","* liquid modifier in my code

[image]

Comment: I think you can attach the screenshot from the GTM debugger and we can see the parameters and values in the hit.

Comment: @Darrellwan Thank you, I have attached now a screenshot

Comment: if your price is 39.90. You might need to replace the comma "," to period "."  
Here is the document from google. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#example